# Seamless Textures in Voxel Worlds

Tags: c++, minecraft, vulkan, voxel

I've been working on a minecraft clone recently and I've been able to generate simple infinite worlds with some noise for height Maps etc but the problem I'm facing are the textures. As you can see in the image below the Textures have some kind of border. They aren't seamless.I use a sprite sheet to send a single texture to the GPU and then Use Different Texture Coords for different BlockTypes.Also I'm using Vulkan As the Rendering Backend and here are some texturing details. I Would really Appreciate some insight on how to tackle this problem.

[image]

```
    VkSamplerCreateInfo sInfo{};
    sInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SAMPLER_CREATE_INFO;
    sInfo.pNext = nullptr;

    sInfo.magFilter = VK_FILTER_NEAREST;
    sInfo.minFilter = VK_FILTER_LINEAR;
    sInfo.addressModeU = VK_SAMPLER_ADDRESS_MODE_REPEAT;
    sInfo.addressModeV = VK_SAMPLER_ADDRESS_MODE_REPEAT;
    sInfo.addressModeW = VK_SAMPLER_ADDRESS_MODE_REPEAT;
    sInfo.anisotropyEnable = VK_TRUE;

    VkPhysicalDeviceProperties Props;
    vkGetPhysicalDeviceProperties(Engine::Get().GetGpuHandle(), &Props);

    sInfo.maxAnisotropy = Props.limits.maxSamplerAnisotropy;
    sInfo.borderColor = VK_BORDER_COLOR_FLOAT_OPAQUE_BLACK;
    sInfo.unnormalizedCoordinates = VK_FALSE;
    sInfo.compareEnable = VK_FALSE;
    sInfo.compareOp = VK_COMPARE_OP_ALWAYS;
    sInfo.mipmapMode = VK_SAMPLER_MIPMAP_MODE_LINEAR;
    sInfo.mipLodBias = 0.f;
    sInfo.minLod = 0.f;
    sInfo.maxLod = 1;

    VkImageCreateInfo iInfo{};
    iInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_CREATE_INFO;
    iInfo.pNext = nullptr;
    iInfo.arrayLayers = 1;
    iInfo.extent = { extent.width,extent.height,1 };
    iInfo.imageType = VK_IMAGE_TYPE_2D;
    iInfo.initialLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED;
    iInfo.mipLevels = 1;
    iInfo.samples = samples;
    iInfo.flags = 0;
    iInfo.tiling = VK_IMAGE_TILING_OPTIMAL;
    Info.usage = VK_IMAGE_USAGE_SAMPLED_BIT | VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL;
    iInfo.format = format;
    iInfo.sharingMode = VK_SHARING_MODE_EXCLUSIVE;
   
    VkImageViewCreateInfo vInfo{};
    vInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_VIEW_CREATE_INFO;
    vInfo.pNext = nullptr;
    vInfo.image = m_Image;
    vInfo.viewType = VK_IMAGE_VIEW_TYPE_2D;
    vInfo.format = format;
    vInfo.flags = 0;
    vInfo.subresourceRange.aspectMask = VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT;
    vInfo.subresourceRange.baseMipLevel = 0;
    vInfo.subresourceRange.levelCount = 1;
    vInfo.subresourceRange.baseArrayLayer = 0;
    vInfo.subresourceRange.layerCount = 1;
```

First I thought It's an issue with my sprite sheet so I different ones but that wasn't the problem it seems. Then I tried several other sampler parameter combinations but still No Luck

Comment: Probably easiest to just put borders on your sprites then adjust your texture coordinates to not go right up to the edges